# Is it possible to escape quotes within escape quotes within escape quotes within escape quotes?

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I'm trying to do is run a command inside an...

```
su - someuser -c "ssh someplace \"if ( ! grep <b>[WHAT DO I PUT HERE?]</b>some thing<b>[WHAT DO I PUT HERE]</b> /etc/somefile ); then doSomething; fi\""
```

It's those quotes for the grep string which are confusing me, I'll get around it by grepping for something without spaces for now,  but I'd rather grep for the thing I want to grep for.

Comment: What is the `su` for? Does your user not have privilege to use network? There is nothing in the `ssh` that needs any special privilege, there for I see no need to use `su`.

Comment: @richard that guy has the key

Comment: Ahh! it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing three quotes doesn't help, you just unquote, quote, and unquote again. You also don't need the subshell.

What you really want is:

```
su - someuser -c 'ssh someplace "if ! grep \"some thing\" /etc/somefile; then doSomething; fi"'
```

This kind of approach can become unwieldy quickly -- consider just putting a script on your server and executing that. That would keep you far away from nested quote hell.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think i'll switch it around, I just used double quotes in the first place out of convenience since I wrap the ssh command part in some annoying php script I'm still working out the kinks on.

Comment: @PeterTurner You can use double quotes here as well if you like, but you'll need to escape the escape (ie. use `\\"`), since otherwise it will be interpreted by the second shell.

Comment: OK, thanks, just thinking about it with the mixture of single quotes and escaped quotes worked.  But there's no more hidden subliminal variations on quotes that bash recognizes right?

Comment: Well, there are a few "special" types like `$'` and `$"`, but you're unlikely to need them outside of very specific situations. Maybe this page might help: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: `"` then `\"` then `\\"` then, can you guess, `\\\\"` then `\\\\\\\\"`. If you get this many then consider that the design of the program is not good. Like with nested `if`s if you get to more than 3 levels then the answer to “Is there a better way?” is yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a here document.

```sh
su -someuser -c '<&1 >&2 ssh you@machine sh' 1<<\SCRIPT
    if   ! grep 'some spaces or whatever' /etc/somefile
    then : do something
    fi
#END
SCRIPT
```

The solution requires a little fd juggling because you'll need to get past the initial password read from `su`, and `su` won't pass on any file-descriptors above 2. But once you've authenticated `su`, `ssh` won't screw with i/o and so you can do the reassignment immediately and let your invoked shell on the other end read stdin.

Comment: I think you mean the password on 'sudo', not 'su' (but your meaning is clear).  I always mention this, but if you're automating SSH calls in scripts, consider using "NOPASSWD all:all" in /etc/sudoers. The benefits of sudo passwd are completely lost in a script (no reason to "give one pause"), and it doesn't lessen security any (either someone has the secrets to that user or they don't... making them enter the same thing twice won't help any).   Far better is a passwordless login using SSH public keys to authenticate. But I'm way off your comment, just remarking for other folks..